# Mysql workbeanch is not autorefreshing data in tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using Mysql Workbeanch 6 , its actually not  refreshing table data when any new insert or Delete is made , and showing old data... any idea

Comment: Do a `commit` or `rollback` before refreshing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto refreshing loaded data is risky as it may load a lot of unwanted data, not to mention problems when the current data is changed. There's also no notification scheme for changed data on a server, so MySQL Workbench would have to poll in regular intervals which most developers certainly don't want.

If you really think MySQL Workbench should have a switchable auto refresh of data then file a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com.